# Postgres server keeps getting terminated by signal 13

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm running a few Docker containers of the official PostgreSQL image (PostgreSQL 15.4). I'm getting the following error in all my containers:

```
2023-09-15 03:41:37.338 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-09-15 03:41:37.333 UTC [127569] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.004 s, sync=0.002 s, total=0.015 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-09-15 03:41:37.321 UTC [127569] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
2023-09-15 03:41:37.317 UTC [127568] LOG:  redo done at 0/5CC8B88 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
2023-09-15 03:41:37.317 UTC [127568] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/5CC8BC0: wanted 24, got 0
2023-09-15 03:41:37.317 UTC [127568] LOG:  redo starts at 0/5CC8AD8
2023-09-15 03:41:37.314 UTC [127568] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-09-15 03:41:37.305 UTC [127568] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-09-15 03:27:08 UTC
2023-09-15 03:41:37.295 UTC [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2023-09-15 03:41:37.294 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2023-09-15 03:41:37.294 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 127563) was terminated by signal 13: Broken pipe
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Most likely something happend before, check your logfiles. And look for something like fsync, because it looks like a corrupted database cluster.

Answer (score -1):

based on [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/docker-sudden-death-for-postgresql/) post the error message `Signal 13 Broken pipe` is because you are running `psql` command in Postgres container.

I once had the same problem where Postgres logs were

```
2023-11-27 13:01:17.903 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 19878) was terminated by signal 13: Broken pipe
2023-11-27 13:01:17.903 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2023-11-27 13:01:17.903 UTC [20430] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2023-11-27 13:01:17.903 UTC [20430] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2023-11-27 13:01:17.903 UTC [20430] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2023-11-27 13:01:17.915 UTC [20434] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2023-11-27 13:01:17.918 UTC [20436] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2023-11-27 13:01:17.918 UTC [20438] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
```

and the docker compose file was

```
  postgres:
    healthcheck:
      test: psql "postgresql://$$POSTGRES_USER:$$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@$$DB_HOST/$$POSTGRES_DB"
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
```

that means in the Postgres container this health check command is regularly executed to monitor the readiness of the container. now if the load on the Postgres is too much then Signal 13: Broken pipe will show up because of the `psql` process.

### SOLUTION

Don't use `psql` use something like `pg_isready`

```
healthcheck:
  test: "pg_isready -h $DB_HOST -p $POSTGRES_PORT -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB"
```